# Why isn't .NET Core 3.1 showing up in Visual Studio after Iinstalled it?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

Just installed .NET Core version 3.1.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, version 16.4.2, so it should be compatible.

But when I try to "create a new project" nothing Core-related shows up in the list, no matter how many ways I try to query.

I'm told it should show up but it doesn't. Haven't a clue as to why (I assume I've missed a step along the way).

Comment: Restart Visual Studio? Have you tried turning it off and back on again?

Comment: Sure, if you mean by "restart" simply closing VS, then launching again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2019 16.4.x will always have .NET Core 3.1 as its main target by default, and VS 2019 16.4.0 or later will always install .NET Core 3.1.100 SDK if you select .NET Core workload when you install VS 2019.

If it's not shown when creating new project, then you have to ensure that you have selected the .NET Core workload when you install VS 2019:

[image: VS 2019 16.4.2 workloads]

Comment: Ahh, so you think the problem can be traced back to the original installation?

Comment: yes, please check the installed VS 2019 workload first.

Comment: I definitely have ".Net Core cross-platform development" installed. My configuration looks much  like your screen shot. But when I drill down it also says it's ".Net Core 2.1 LTS Runtime." That doesn't sound right to me. Should I be using SDK?

Comment: So I'm thinking, what, uninstall 2.1 runtime, which I believe is being picked up at the target now, and install 3.1??

Answer (score 1):

[Eriawan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59570067/why-isnt-net-core-3-1-showing-up-in-visual-studio-after-iinstalled-it/59570183#59570183) pointed me in the right direction. The problem was, as suspected, very simple. I had bypassed Core when first installing VS 2019. Just had to use the Installer and install to fix.